# How to implement local communication in Atmosphere?

Tags: java, atmosphere

I am using latest atmosphere.js.

I tried using onLocalMessage event and pushLocal. But, I am not understanding how to exactly use these in my chat application.

I have referred [this link](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Atmosphere-1.1).